MS Teams Tab Application
I have a Blazor tab application that sends a card to a Channel for users' notification. The card has an action button that uses the OpenUrl action to send the users back to the tab app. The problem is that when I install the App and I get the url from teams: if I use that url in the Action button and install again. The tab url changes. How can I get the application id programmatically, to update the url in the Action Button at run time?
Thanks in advance.

After some testing, I figured out that the issue happens in the local debug environment. Once I deploy to the cloud it works fine, because the tab is not deleted every single time.
